# Hibernate query using or shows no results

Tags: hibernate, hql

We're trying to execute the following query through HQL, but we're stuck and this query is showing us no results.

```
select s from Serie s where
(s.arrivalSerie is not null and s.arrivalSerie.company.isEnable=1)
or (s.departureSerie is not null and s.departureSerie.company.isEnable=1)
```

We're throwing this query with:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("previous query");
query.setFirstResult(initialElement);
```

While testing this query we find out any part of this query ("or") can be executed with results. But when the whole query is executed we get 0 elements collection.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

An understandable translated query would be something like this:

```
select
        s.*
    from
        serie s,
        arrivalSerie a,
        company ca,
        departureSerie d,
        company cd 
    where
        s.idArrivalSerie=a.idArrivalSerie 
        and a.CompanyCode=ca.CompanyCode 
        and s.idDepartureSerie=d.idDepartureSerie 
        and d.CompanyCode=cd.CompanyCode 
        and (
            (
                s.idArrivalSerie is not null
            ) 
            and ca.isEnable=1 
            or (
                s.idDepartureSerie is not null
            ) 
            and cd.isEnable=1
        ) limit 0,10;
```

Of course this is not showing us results on a MySql Client

Comment: Can you check the sql generated out of this hql?

Comment: You can debug this by setting the show-sql property to true in the hibernate config, the console will print the SQL query that is generated, you can run it against your DB and find out .

Comment: What does the variable `initialElement` contain? If you want the first element you should set it as 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s.arrivalSerie.company
```

creates an inner join between `Serie` and `ArrivalSerie`, and another inner join between `ArrivalSerie` and `Company`. And an inner join will filter out all the Series that have a null arrivalSerie, which is clearly not what you want. So you need to use left joins instead:

```
select s from Serie s 
left join s.arrivalSerie arrivalSerie
left join arrivalSerie.company arrivalCompany
left join s.departureSerie departureSerie
left join departureSerie.company departureCompany
where arrivalCompany.isEnable = 1 or departureCompany.isEnable = 1
```

Comment: thanks, we finally find out the same solution on our own. Anyway the explanation is appreciated (honestly we didn't know exactly what was happening with the initial query).

Comment: You should always turn SQL logging on during developement, to see how Hibernate translates HQL to SQL, and find the reason of such problems.